# AWS EB deployment errors - No module named cfnbootstrap

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it states some errors when the process is completed and reading the logs this is what I've found:

```
File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata", line 18, in <module>
import cfnbootstrap
ImportError: No module named cfnbootstrap (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Why is this happening? is this module supposed to be already installed into the AWS EB instances? it's not part of my application.

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a solution for this but I noticed that both versions 2.6 and 2.7 are installed in the AWS elastic beanstalk instance and thanks to these EB configs ([Getting a python 2.7 project running on elastic-beanstalk](http://leetreveil.roon.io/getting-a-python-2-7-project-running-on-elastic-beanstalk) i managed to force the use of the 2.7 only and the error did not happens anymore.

If you are having the same problem have a look of the updated files on GitHub as well: [Elastic beanstalk python 27](https://github.com/marko85to/elasticbeanstalk-python27)